# Using Lag Function at the exception of the last row

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I want to get the % difference between last_value and last_value 7 days prior.
This is the way I am doing it right now, but would love to have any other suggestions or alternatives:

**Example**
This

date----number_of_users

01/01:             5005

01/02 :            6555

...

*current_date-7:*   5553
...

*current_date:*     6000

I am trying to compared 6000 and 5553. The way I am doing it right is:

```
select 
 date,
 case 
   when date=current_date then number_of_users
   else lag(number_of_users,7) over(order by date) end as lag_7_day
from 
 my_table
```

Let me know if you guys have any alternatives for that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, is this about MySQL or Redshift? They are different database systems so your question should only be tagged with the one your are using.

Comment: I'm lost.  What does your query have to do with the question which is about calculating a percent difference?

Comment: If you GUARANTEE that you have strictly one record per date and strictly no gaps then you may use `SELECT date, value, LAG(value, 7) OVER (order by date)`. IF there are gaps or duplicates by date you may use 2 table copies joined by `t1.date = t2.date + INTERVAL 7 day` (if there is a gap in `t2` for this value you'll get `NULL`, for duplicated you may take some specific value, for example, `MAX()`) or correlated query (in which you may approximate the value if it is absent).

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for - are you expecting 1 row in your output containing last row and the row 7 days prior or are you expecting all rows with the row 7 days prior?

Answer (score 0):

To compare today with 7 days ago and get a % you need something like this

```
select 
 date,
 number_of_users as number_of_users_current_date,
 lag(number_of_users,7) over(order by date) number_of_users_lag_7_day
 (number_of_users::float -  lag(number_of_users::float,7) over(order by date)) / number_of_users::float as percent_increase
from 
 my_table
where date - current_date()
```